# Pygame Blit Once?

Tags: python, pygame, blit

I'm using Pygame and imported and image into a surface then used the blit command:
screen.blit(surface,(x,y)) but it keep on stacking surfaces, how can I stop it at just 1 surface?

Comment: Do a `screen.fill()` between updates?

Answer (score 0):

You have to blit a background between each update.

```
_________CODE___________
Character.update()
screen.fill(background) # or screen.fill((0,0,0)) for a black background
__________CODE___________
```